# Setting formula that references a non-existing sheet

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I want to build a formula for an excel sheet that references another sheet.
Normally, the code would look something like this

```
 aBook.Worksheets(aSheet).Cells(row, col).FormulaR1C1 = "=bSheet!A1*100"
```

Problem is, `bSheet` doesn't exist yet. If I run the code, the application opens a browser window and wants me to select the missing Workbook/Sheet.

How can I suppress this? The bSheet is generated later in the process, but for maintenance reasons, I don't want to build the formula after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can suppress this and other alerts like this:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

Note that the behaviour you describe is not specific to VBA. The same happens if you manually type `=bSheet!A1*100` in an Excel cell.

Comment: It might be worth noting that this should be set back to `true` when you're done with whatever code is triggering an unwanted alert. Otherwise you risk missing an alert you want to see.